# isogeny of elliptic curves

Tags: abelian-varieties, elliptic-curves, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ and $F$ be two abelian varieties of dimension 1 over $\mathbb{C}$.  Let $f : E \to F$ be a surjective homomorphism of abelian varieties ($f(0) = 0$).  If $\ker (f) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, does this imply that $E$ and $F$ are isomorphic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. In zero characteristic the image of an isogeny of elliptic curves
is determined up to isomorphism by its kernel. Your isogeny has the same kernel
as the doubling map from $E$ to itself.

Comment: @Robin: could you please provide a hint on how one proves this statement (that the image is determined by ker)? thanks

Comment: Think about the usual isomorphism theorems for groups. The map E -> F kills ker f, so factors as E -> E/(ker f) -> F. Since degrees are multiplicative the map E/(ker f) - > F has degree 1, so must be an isomorphism. 

Comment: The same holds in positive characteristic, as long as "kernel" is interpreted scheme-theoretically. In particular, if the kernel of f   is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$ (as a constant group scheme), then $E \cong F$.  

Comment: To add to JT's remark, we also need that when $f_1:E\to F_1$
and $f_2:E\to F_2$ are isogenies of elliptic curves with $f_1$
separable and $\ker f_1\subseteq\ker f_2$ then there is an isogeny
$g:F_1\to F_2$ with $f_2=gf_1$. Over $\mathbb{C}$ where
elliptic curves are complex tori, this is quite easy to prove.
Over general fields it requires more work; see Silverman's
book for instance.

Comment: that makes lots of sense.  thanks a lot everyone!